# 0xC0000005: Access violation appears suddenly

Tags: c++, mfc

after some time my service suddenly crashes. I analysed it with VS 2012 it says it is an an access violation. I actually cannot imagine this.

Function where it happens:

```
void CTItem::WrapPacketClient(CPacket * pPacket, DWORD dwCharID, BYTE bAddItemID, WORD 

wUseTime, BYTE bCashItem)

{
    BYTE bRegGuild = FALSE;

if( m_dwExtValue[IEV_GUILD] &&
    m_dwExtValue[IEV_GUILD] == dwCharID)
    bRegGuild = TRUE;

if(bAddItemID)
    (*pPacket) << m_bItemID;

(*pPacket)
    << m_wItemID
    << m_bLevel
    << m_bCount
    << m_dwDuraMax
    << m_dwDuraCur
    << m_pTITEM->m_bRefineMax
    << m_bRefineCur
    << m_bGLevel;

if(bCashItem)
    (*pPacket) << wUseTime;
else
    (*pPacket) << m_dEndTime;

(*pPacket)
    << m_bGradeEffect
    << BYTE(m_dwExtValue[IEV_ELD])
    << BYTE(m_dwExtValue[IEV_WRAP])
    << WORD(m_dwExtValue[IEV_COLOR])
    << bRegGuild
    << BYTE(m_mapTMAGIC.size());

MAPTMAGIC::iterator itTMAGIC;
for( itTMAGIC = m_mapTMAGIC.begin(); itTMAGIC != m_mapTMAGIC.end(); itTMAGIC++)
{
    (*pPacket)
        << (*itTMAGIC).first
        << GetMagicValue((*itTMAGIC).second);
}
}
```

VS 12 says the access violation occurs here: `m_mapTMAGIC.begin()`

MAPTMAGIC is a custom class of std::map (`typedef map< BYTE, LPTMAGIC>              MAPTMAGIC, *LPMAPTMAGIC;`). `m_mapTMAGIC` is also a member of it.

GetMagicValue function:

```
WORD CTItem::GetMagicValue( LPTMAGIC pTMAGIC)
{
    LPTITEMMAGIC pMagic = pTMAGIC->m_pMagic;

    FLOAT fRevision = FLOAT(pMagic->m_bRvType ? m_pTITEM->m_fRevision[pMagic->m_bRvType-1] : 1.0);
    WORD wValue = WORD(fRevision * pTMAGIC->m_wValue * pMagic->m_wMaxValue) / 100;
    return max(wValue, 1);
}
```

This function is used to calculate the value of (*itTMAGIC).second. (*itTMAGIC).first selects the ID for the value (which type it actually is).

Hopefully you will have an idea why it crashes.

This application is a MFC application. It is written in VS 2003. I use Windows Server 2008 x64 to run it.

Comment: Something must be corrupting your data from outside of this function. Did you try to run a debug build? Also, is it possible that `m_mapTMAGIC` is being modified in another thread while `WrapPacketClient()` is executing?

Comment: That is the NTSTATUS code for an access violation. You'll need to do some debugging.

Comment: It is a little strange, most obvious reasons why m_mapTMAGIC.begin would fail would also see m_mapTMAGIC.size() fail a few lines above.
like pvgoran, I would wonder about other threads being an issue?

Comment: btwm `(*itTMAGIC).first` is the less readable friend of `itTMAGIC->first`. Potentially less efficient too.

Comment: There isnt actually any other issue as far as i can think. I will upload the file for you. Maybe you find something i do not. I have already tried to use itTMAGIC->first but nothing. Still the same issue.

Comment: Here is the link: https://mega.co.nz/#!zEU1BKyL

Comment: @user3100736: you can attach a debugger to the service after it starts. It's also possible to configure things so the service starts under the debugger, or you can have the debugger automatically attached when the crash occurs and/or get a crash dump file that can be loaded into a debugger on your dev machine.  There are many options available to debug or troubleshoot a crashing service, but they do take some configuration. Also, it can usually be arranged to run a service as a normal console program with a little bit of work in the program's initialization.

Comment: Im already getting and reading from my dump file. When the services crashes I get a dump file. It directly leads me to the point which i have shown to you.

Comment: So, does `m_mapTMAGIC` look corrupt? What about the `CTItem` that contains the `m_mapTMAGIC` member - has it been corrupted (or maybe it has been destroyed already)?

Comment: Here you find the `CTItem` class: https://mega.co.nz/#!yQVjQZhB For me it doesnt seem corrupted or even destroyed.

Comment: Class definotions of CTItem: https://mega.co.nz/#!yQVjQZhB!O186JUJ1IAAVpQWwIkXe9EqDNxVrclVaZfiPAkinRQ4  CPP file: https://mega.co.nz/#!zEU1BKyL!B1mEcCBPNM1MFsYMKXufwgsUKk1emNfyTXbDzlM_1wM  - Forgot to add the key for the link last time - sorry.

Comment: The source files don't say much about the runtime state of the objects.  Also, if you're going to post source, my preference is to edit it into the question (if the number of files is low and the size is reasonable for in a question); if they have to be posted on something other than SO (for large files or too many files), a github gist or repository is better, I think.

Comment: ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for ntdll.dll - 
This dump file has an exception of interest stored in it.
The stored exception information can be accessed via .ecxr.
(7bc.1ab0): Access violation - code c0000005 (first/second chance not available)
eax=00000000 ebx=00706b10 ecx=007ae838 edx=007ae838 esi=00706ae8 edi=00706b40
eip=77910c42 esp=0525ecf8 ebp=0525ed08 iopl=0         nv up ei pl zr na pe nc
cs=0023  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00000246
ntdll!NtGetContextThread+0x12:
77910c42 83c404          add     esp,4

Comment: This is the result of the debugging session.

Comment: This is not the result. This is your starting point. Inspect the objects. Do they look ok? Are they messed up? Did you run a debug build? Debug builds fill memory with predefined patterns, and surround memory areas with guard bytes. This should get you going. Also, are there any other threads in your service?

Comment: If I use the debug build nothing works anymore. How can I inspect the objects (Sorry - Im debugging like this the first time) ? And yes there are other threads. He even leads me to a thread (sorry for not mentioning). Here is a link where you can see all other threads: https://mega.co.nz/#!fNV0GAAC!CPepHxBcUh9RXaw5VngOkn36pB4QRKtyeaHbwX3kD70
Search for BatchThread in TMapSvr.cpp this is the thread which makes trouble.

Comment: Does any one have an idea ?

Comment: Here you can find all the files on github if you prefer this: https://github.com/xCollo/Violation

Comment: First step: Get your debug configuration in shape. It has instrumentation built in that gets you closer to the cause of the problem.

Comment: I have tidied up my Debugger:

Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 6.10.0003.233 X86
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.


Loading Dump File [C:\TServices_GSP\TMapSvr(2013-12-13-23-59-55).dmp]
User Mini Dump File with Full Memory: Only application data is available

Comment: WARNING: Minidump contains unknown stream type 0x1
Symbol search path is: .sympath c:\mypdbs;srv*c:\msftpdbs*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
Executable search path is: 
Windows 7 Version 7601 (Service Pack 1) MP (4 procs) Free x86 compatible
Product: Server, suite: Enterprise TerminalServer SingleUserTS
Machine Name:
Debug session time: Fri Dec 13 23:59:55.000 2013 (GMT+1)
System Uptime: 1 days 5:39:15.646
Process Uptime: 0 days 0:27:33.000

Comment: .....................................................
Loading unloaded module list
.
This dump file has an exception of interest stored in it.
The stored exception information can be accessed via .ecxr.
(d0c.1228): Access violation - code c0000005 (first/second chance not available)
eax=00000000 ebx=006fc3f8 ecx=00c1e838 edx=00c1e838 esi=006fc3d0 edi=006fc428
eip=77910c42 esp=048cecf8 ebp=048ced08 iopl=0         nv up ei pl zr na pe nc
cs=0023  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00000246
ntdll!ZwGetContextThread+0x12:
77910c42 83c404          add     esp,4

Comment: Ok, my debugger says now: > ntdll.dll!___RtlUserThreadStart@8() Unbekannt
and   ntdll.dll!__RtlUserThreadStart@8() Unbekannt
Iam loading the symbols from the microsoft server now. Hope this helps you.

Comment: Does sombody has an idea ?